# Placing a paragraph into a textbox

Tags: minipage, text, fbox

I am busy helping someone to write a book using texstudio, and I am trying to add a specific paragraph into a textbox as a sort of short story within the book.  I used the minipage method to do so, but all the paragraphs after the minipage has weird formatting.  Up until the minipage everything is fine. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}

\author{TeXstudio Team}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{January 2013}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\include{Inleiding}
%\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}
\part{Deel Een}
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}
\part{Last part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
%...
\chapter{Last chapter}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

\end{document}
```

This is the packages and structure I have on the main page, and the problem comes here:

```
Die konserwatiewe gereformeerde kerkmense het hewig gereageer en daar is met minagting na hulle as die Wederdopers en ‘n sekte verwys. Die Pinkster gelowiges is beskou as eenvoudige, ongeletterde mense en moes baie spot verduur. Hierdie venyn het voortgeduur en later onder die Nasionale regering wat sterk onder die invloed van die Broederbond gestaan het, is ernstig teen hierdie mense gediskrimineer wat betref werkverkryging en bevorderings.\\

\medskip

\centering\fcolorbox{white}{mygray}{
    \begin{minipage}{20em}
        Ons Farrell kinders het grootoog gesit en luister na die vertelling van hoe ou Broer Henning besig was om in ‘n saal te preek toe iemand ‘n klip van buite deur ‘n venster gooi en die prediker rakelings mis. Sonder om sy preek te onderbreek sê die ou Broer “vervloek is die hand wat die klip gegooi het”
        Later die dag bring iemand die tyding dat ‘n persoon in die plaaslike hospitaal die ou Broer wou sien. Verbaas hieroor omdat nie een van sy kudde in die hospitaal was nie, volg hy nogtans die boodskapper en vind ‘n jongman in die hospitaal met verbande om sy hand. Toe hy navraag doen sê die jongman “Pastoor, dit is die hand wat die klip gegooi het” Kort na die klipgooi insident het sy hand in ‘n rat van ‘n masjien beland wat dit vergruis het.
        Dieselfde prediker was besig om bekeerlinge in die rivier te doop, toe ‘n groep spotters ‘n hond gryp en spottenderwys die dier doop. Die ou broer het opgekyk en met gesag gesê “dra die lyk uit”. Die jongman het net daar gesterf.
    \end{minipage}
}

\medskip

\section{Politiek en my Lewe}
Maar daar was die ander stroom, die politieke stroom. Verhale uit die Anglo-Boereoorlog het in my jong gemoed as kind geresoneer en die onregte wat deur die magtige Britse ryk teen die Afrikanervolk gepleeg is het ’n bitterheid in my jong gemoed laat posvat.\\

Vertellings deur my familie wat nog in die Anglo Boereoorlog geveg het, of in die kampe aangehou en selfs gesterf het het my lewensuitkyk in ‘n ander rigting as Goddelikheid gestuur.\\

\subsection{Circa 1847}
Selfs gebeure uit die verre verlede het bygedra om my gemoedstoestand in die ander rigting te kleur. Ek verwys hier na my Ierse afkoms en die gebeure in Ierland tydens die groot hongersnood wat bygedra het om my jong seunsgemoed met veglustigheid te vul. Weens ‘n byna wêreldwye uitbraak van ‘n swamsiekte onder artappels rondom 1847, het aartappelpryse op die Londonse mark weens tekorte tot astronomiese hoogtes gestyg.   Britse grondeienaars het al wat aartappel in Ierland was op die Londonse mark verkoop. ‘n Ernstige hongersnood het gevolg in Ierland waartydens baie Iere gesterf het waaronder waarskynlik van my voorsate.   Kinders wat wees agter gelaat is, is onseremonieel op skepe gelaai en na Kanada, Amerika, Suid Afrika en Australie gedeporteer. So het John Farrell, my grootoupa, hom op jeugdige leeftyd in Kaapstad bevind. Verbittering teenoor die Britte weens die rol wat hulle in hierdie tragedie gespeel het, is deur oorvertelling stelselmatig in my kindergemoed vasgelê.\\
```

This is how the text looks up to and including the minipage:
[image]

and this is how the text looks directly after the minipage:
[image]

Comment: Well, you have `\centering`. You might want to try `\begin{center}...\end{center}` instead.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.